# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException - Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, json, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am trying to connect to one web service with my windows store app (I am very new with it) with no luck. My app is installed on my local machine.

What I am doing is creating my json class and send it to this webservice.
I am using this code:

```
try {


            string requestURL = "http://192.168.1.100:8082/mydir/sendtoWs?saParams=";

             ...
             Uri requestUri = new Uri(requestUrl);
             using (var client = new HttpClient())
             {
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("ISO-8859-1"));
                 var requestContent = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                 requestContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
                 var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, requestContent);

                 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                 {

                     Debug.WriteLine("Success");
                     ...
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Debug.WriteLine("Unsuccessful!");
                     ...

                 }
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex) {
             Debug.WriteLine("ex: " + ex.Message);
             Debug.WriteLine("inner message: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
          }
```

this is the exception that I am getting

```
'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.dll
ex: An error occurred while sending the request.
inner message: Unable to connect to the remote server
```

if I try to put in my browser the url included with the json I am getting the proper response and also

if I use another website for instance this: http://ip.jsontest.com/

I am getting a response.

- What could be my problem?

Please note:

Similar code is working on my windows phone app but using another type of web service.

I set up all the permissions in my manifest (internet, private network etc).

I am able to connect my app to the internet (I have a webview with www.google.com displayed)

I tried also to disable my firewall.

Comment: You're trying to browse that url on device browser and works fine?

Comment: Your aware that 192.168.1.100 is a *local* address?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi, I dont have a device to test the brower but inside a webview I am just seeing a blank page with that page. Alex k. yes I am aware of it